# what keeps turning off stickykeys and how do I stop it?

Tags: x11, xkb, accessibility

I have `xkbset st -twokeys` in `~/.xsession` file. My process list is (mine, not system):

```
winbindd: domain child
/lib/systemd/systemd --user
(sd-pam)
/usr/bin/pipewire
/usr/bin/wireplumber
/usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
/usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
ratpoison
pulseaudio
xscreensaver
xscreensaver-systemd
bash
rdesktop
ps -ef
grep
```

`xkbset st` turns on stickykeys; when you press ctrl, alt, or shift it stays pressed until the next keystroke. `-twokeys` prevents it from being turned off by the normal keyboard disabling action of modifier pressed with normal.

How do I get stickykeys to stay on? Something is turning it off on a timer.

How often? About every 15 minutes.

This is definitely Xorg not Wayland. The window manager is `ratpoison`.

OS: Debian Bookworm x64

Here's an outside link to a very similar problem, but it's not caused by keyboard connection  problems for me. https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/setxkbmap-keeps-resetting/17648

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) ask a question. If it is the one in the title, please repeat it so we know what is being asked. ii) tell us your operating system. iii) describe what you expect to happen and explain what is actually happening instead. What do you expect from `xkbset st -twokeys` and what do you get? What happens every 15 minutes? iv) tell us what graphical environment you are using. First, is it X or Wayland? Then, what desktop environment. Gnome? Cinnamon? KDE? Something else?

Comment: @terdon: effectively this is the null graphical environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X is turning it off again. For some reason that doesn't make sense anymore, sticky keys, two keys, mouse keys, slow keys, bounce keys, and beep when LED changes expire.

Solution: `xkbset exp =st` in addition to the enabling command.

This changes sticky keys and two keys to be non expiring.

Comment: `xkbset` and X11 accessibility is poorly documented. There is a little more help in the output of `xkbset h`. You can use `xkbset q exp` to find the current no-activity expiration timeout (in seconds), which seems to default to 120 seconds. It also lists which features will be turned off, turned on, or left unchanged on timeout. `xkbset w exp` will provide the same information in the form of an equivalent xkbset command.